# Why do mourners study Mishnah Kelim, Ch. 24 and Mikvaos, Ch. 7?

Tags: minhag, mishna, mourning-aveilus

Mourners traditionally study two chapters of the Mishnah, these two chapters being [Kelim Ch. 24](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kelim.24?lang=bi) and [Mikvaos Ch. 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Mikvaot.7?lang=bi).

Besides these sections having to do with ritual purity, what is the underlying reason behind the study of these two chapters?

Comment: Can you source your first sentence? Mourners during Shiva at least are forbidden from studying texts like these. Do you mean during Shloshim?

Comment: I’ve heard of doing Mikvaos, but what communities do Keilim?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, I mean during the 11 months after the family member passes away.

Answer (score 4):

I [recently learned](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-10th-birthday-lets-divide-and-conquer-the-entire-mish/5087#5087) Mikvaot for the MiYodeya 10-year siyum Mishnayot and noticed artscroll there explains

> The study of the [seventh chapter of Mikvaot] is considered especially
>   meritorious, because **the first letters of the last four Mishnas spell
>   *neshama* (soul)** at the end of the chapter [R Yitzchak Isaac of Komarna]. It is therefore customary to study the chapter at a house of
>   mourners during the thirty-day or one-year mourning period, and on the
>   *yahrzeit* (anniversary of death).

Similarly on Keilim ch. 24 they write

> It is worth noting that the present chapter is singled out from all
>   the chapters in Mishnah as being particularly propitious for study in
>   memory of a deceased loved one. This is because **each of the chapter's
>   first sixteen mishnahs ends with the phrase טְהוֹרָה מִכְּלוּם *"it is pure from any form
>   of tumah"***, and the seventheenth and final mishnah also concludes with
>   the word *tahor* (pure) [Ta'amei HaMinhagim, footnote to *Kuntres
>   Acharon* #1071]

Comment: Is four mishnayot spelling a word that unique? Those are all relatively common letters too. Can anyone confirm if there are any other examples of this in the Mishna?

Comment: @DoubleAA I vaguely recall reading a piece about other examples but I’m not sure; can’t remember if others were pointed to or none were found. However, I am pretty sure the the Komarna Rav’s discovery was more complex than the simple acronym of נ-ש-מ-ה (the way Artscroll apparently makes it appear).

Comment: @DoubleAA I looked up the Komarna’s Maase Oreg (ch. 7, end) and indeed he records a longer acronym (the first 3 *mishnayot* form א-י-ה) with its broad *kabbalistic* significance and appropriate intentions.